# Display data in a loop using laravel?

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a simple analytics page for my website that shows data from my database.

Part of the data looks like this:

`school ID: [ID here]` - `Inquiries: [number of inquiries here]`  `Applications: [Number of Applications here]`

the database table has multiple columns including `school_id` and `type`.

This is my **code**:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM school_attendants WHERE type='application' AND type='inquiry'";
                $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                ?>

                @foreach($school_id as $school_id)
                    {{$school_id->school_id}} - Inquiries: {{$inquiries->count()}}  Applications: {{$applications->count()}}<br/>
                @endforeach
```

It should basically go into the school_attendants table and find and display every school_id that is in there and count the number of times "application" and "inquiry" occur for a particular school_id.

example: if school_id of 135 is in the table 20 times and 10 of those times has "application" in the type column and the other 10 times has "inquiry" in the type column, the code should display:

`school ID: 135`   `Inquiries: 10`  `Applications: 10`

then repeat for other school_id's it finds in the table.

the error I am currently getting is:

`Undefined variable: school_id`

Comment: Im confused a bit. Why are you writing down queries in a view if you are using laravel? You "queried" your sql command but did not fetch the results. Your foreach can't declare the same variable, try changing to @foreach($school_id as $id). Where the $school_id comes from?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm looking at one of my old codes that works and it has SQL queries in the view file.  school_id is a column name in the database.

Comment: Someone didn't do his [homework](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/readme). You should learn the basics of your framework before trying stuff out.

Comment: @Stefmachine that's not a solution to the problem even though yes, that's a good tip.  other people helped me with some other code.  I'm making an attempt at creating this file because those other people are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Yes it works but you throw at the garbage all the benefits of your framework. The right way to fetch a query in laravel is to use the eloquent methods. Please read all of this page before start coding. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent. You might also consider watch the full laravel from scratch series at laracasts.com

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for being harsh at you. Sadly, the solution to your problem has many more layers than what a simple StackOverflow question can be answered with. You are trying to use a framework without understanding the patterns used within. 

We cannot teach you how to use the framework but we can show you some good resources for you to learn. Solving your problem "as is" would end up being bad programmation practice. 

Have a nice day nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Using the native php without frameworks just like you are doing, you might succeed doing this:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM school_attendants WHERE type='application' AND type='inquiry'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
@if($result->num_rows > 0) 
    @while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        <!--Do your Logic You can dump the $row to see how the data is set.-->
    @endwhile
@endif
```